# how to insert json file into javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsfiddle

I have a simple problem but i cann't solve it!!! I have a simple json file with points.. Every single point has coordinates (long,lat) and an id. This file i want to insert into a table in javascript with JsFiddle. (Afterwards, i want to use every single pair of coordinates in order to create one another feature and to export also a json file with coordinates and this feature but this is not my problem right now :P ). I enclosed this json file.. Thank you have a nice day! :)

My **json** file:

```
   {
    "displayFieldName": "",
    "fieldAliases": {
        "FID": "FID",
        "Id": "Id",
        "Longtitude": "Longtitude",
        "Latitude": "Latitude"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 4326,
        "latestWkid": 4326
    },
    "fields": [{
        "name": "FID",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
        "alias": "FID"
    }, {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
        "alias": "Id"
    }, {
        "name": "Longtitude",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
        "alias": "Longtitude"
    }, {
        "name": "Latitude",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
        "alias": "Latitude"
    }],
    "features": [{
        "attributes": {
            "FID": 0,
            "Id": 1,
            "Longtitude": 23.739000000000001,
            "Latitude": 37.972000000000001
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": 23.739000000000001,
            "y": 37.972000000000001
        }
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "FID": 1,
            "Id": 2,
            "Longtitude": 23.760100000000001,
            "Latitude": 37.984999999999999
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": 23.760100000000001,
            "y": 37.984999999999999
        }
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "FID": 2,
            "Id": 3,
            "Longtitude": 23.749199999999998,
            "Latitude": 37.975999999999999
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": 23.749199999999998,
            "y": 37.975999999999999
        }
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "FID": 3,
            "Id": 4,
            "Longtitude": 23.735700000000001,
            "Latitude": 37.975999999999999
        },
        "geometry": {
            "x": 23.735700000000001,
            "y": 37.975999999999999
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your file.

```
var fileContent = readTextFile("file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt");
fielContent = JSON.parse(fileContent);
```

after this you can do with your json what you want, e.g take each coordinates

```
fileContent.features.each(function(point) {
  console.log(point.geometry.x + " " + point.geometry.y);
});
```

Make sure that you modify for your needs.

Comment: i tried this, but it didnt work. :(  I changed my path and the name of file in "readTextFile" but it didn't work.. Do you know why?? I post my jsfiddle example:

Comment: var fileContent = readTextFile("file:///C:/Python27/jsonsimeia.txt");
fielContent = JSON.parse(fileContent);

fileContent.features.each(function(point) {
  console.log(point.geometry.x + " " + point.geometry.y);
});

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

To load your JSON:

```
function loadJSON(file,callback) {   
      var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
      xobj.open('GET', file, true); 
      xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == '200') {
        // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
          callback(xobj.responseText);
         }
      };
      xobj.send(null);  
}
```

To search through it and get whatever you want:

```
//return an array of objects according to key, value, or key and value matching
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));    
        } else 
        //if key matches and value matches or if key matches and value is not passed (eliminating the case where key matches but passed value does not)
        if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
            objects.push(obj);
        } else if (obj[i] == val && key == ''){
            //only add if the object is not already in the array
            if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1){
                objects.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return objects;
}

//return an array of values that match on a certain key
function getValues(obj, key) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getValues(obj[i], key));
        } else if (i == key) {
            objects.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}

//return an array of keys that match on a certain value
function getKeys(obj, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getKeys(obj[i], val));
        } else if (obj[i] == val) {
            objects.push(i);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Example:

```
loadJSON('index.json', function(text){
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data);

    var files = getObjects(data, 'type', 'file');
    var fileNames = getValues(files, 'name');

    var directories = getObjects(data, 'type','directory');
    var directoryNames = getValues(directories, 'name');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

1. .json file

```
 [
     {
       "Dzień": 1,
       "Dyżur nocny": "Błotna 3",
       "Dyżur świąteczny": "Wojska Polskiego "
     },
     {
       "Dzień": 2,
       "Dyżur nocny": "Zachlapana 9",
       "Dyżur świąteczny": ""
     }
  ]
```

2. .js file

```
 (async function() {
      const url = "s21.json";
      const data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
      console.log(data[1]);
   })();
```

Comment: Hello, i recommend providing some explanation about your answer so it can help new users and future seekers.